# ASP.NET: How to passing multiple QueryString to Gridview as the Parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, parameters, query-string

I have a Link contains QueryString like this

```
http://localhost:11502/Default.aspx?query=123,456
```

the Question is, how i get the `query`of `123,456, etc`to passing it to Gridview as the Parameters?
I've do this below but only the first Parameter shown the Data

```
 Dim xSplit As String = Me.Request.QueryString("query").ToString
 Dim newtstString = xSplit.Split(",")

    For a As Integer = 0 To newtstString.Length
        Dim constr As String = Me.STRCONN_STRING.ToString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newtstString(a)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        Me.Gridview1.DataSource = dt
                        Me.Gridview1.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

Comment: You are binding data in a loop. That is not gonna work, only the last query executed will be visible since the previous ones get overwritten. You should send both parameters to the DB and make sure you get the right results in a single query.

Comment: could you give some example code?

Comment: No, because the problem is not in the above code but in what happens in the database. You need to send the querystring items as separate parameters and make sure your query returns the values you want.